# Maria DB - update row with value of previous row + constant

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mariadb

I have table called **dobridol** with several column.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dobridol` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dt` varchar(200)  NOT NULL,
  `p2` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `p6` int(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `dobridol` (`id`, `dt`, `p2`,`p6`) VALUES
  ('1', '2021-02-28 23:50:00', '100', '600'),
  ('2', '2021-02-28 23:55:00', '200', '700'),
  ('3', '2021-03-01 00:00:00', '300', '800'),
  ('4', '2021-03-01 00:05:00', '400', '900'),
  ('5', '2021-03-01 00:10:00', '400', '900'),
  ('6', '2021-03-01 00:15:00', '400', '900'),
  ('7', '2021-03-01 00:20:00', '500', '1000'),
  ('8', '2021-03-01 00:25:00', '600', '1100');
```

The table has values for January and March also.

I want to be able to UPDATE table like that:

I select period as month, then I add constant value (in this case I added 39) to p6 ONLY WHEN p2 value is different than previous row p2.
If this is the case I have to add 39 to PREVIOUS row p6 value.

```
update dobridol join
       (select tt.*,
               sum(case when p2 <> prev_p2 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by dt) as cnt
        from (select tt.*,
                     lag(p2) over (order by dt) as prev_p2
              from dobridol tt
             ) tt
              
       ) tt
       on tt.id = dobridol.id       
       set dobridol.p6 = cnt * 39 + <PREVIOUS_ROW_p6_VALUE_HAS_TO_BE_HERE>
    where cnt > 0
```

The query should look-like this but I have to replace this <PREVIOUS_ROW_VALUE_HAS_TO_BE_HERE> with the right syntax of picking last row p6. How can I pick it?

Also where to add clause

```
dobridol.dt BETWEEN '2021-03-01' AND '2021-03-30'
```

in the SQL query?

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. Add 2-3 rows for Jan and for Mar. Then show desired output for shown source data for specified period (Feb) and constant value (39). *ONLY WHEN p2 value is different than previous row p2.* For the most first Feb row - does the value for last Jan row must be tested?

Comment: Yes, the value for last Jan row must be tested too

Comment: Store dates using a date data type, and then get back to us.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa7b9a/2 @Strawberry

Comment: I refer you again to my previous comment. And there are no values for January here.

Comment: Dates are this format for reasons not depending on me. I receive them from external HW controller which is writing directly in Database. Let's assume I want to make changes for March, so that's why I did not add Jan.

Comment: *The table has values for January and March also.*

Comment: I do not see why this is so important for you as I told you this sqlfiddle is just an example? I added FEB and March and it is enough to understand completely what I mean and to use it as template for solution

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `lag()`:

```
update dobridol join
       (select tt.*,
               lag(p6) over (order by dt) as prev_p6,
               sum(case when p2 <> prev_p2 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by dt) as cnt
        from (select tt.*,
                     lag(p2) over (order by dt) as prev_p2
              from dobridol tt
             ) tt
       ) tt
       on tt.id = dobridol.id       
       set dobridol.p6 = tt.cnt * 39 + tt.prev_p6
    where cnt > 0 ;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=9d2f398005ad49b7d808ae1ccddaba65) is a db<>fiddle.